# Make transparent 3d object with collision detection

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I am newbie in unity3d, I just want to make a square area which will should be transparent and when a object enter into that square area or touch that area then I should let know that some object enter or touch area. Kindly let me know or suggest me how can i do this task. This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Box collider will work and if you just want to know when they enter click is trigger then in your script have the OnTriggerEnter function to handle your logic

here is a link for unity's colliders
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.html